# I'm getting an InputMismatchException message when uploading a text file?

Tags: java, fileinputstream, inputmismatchexception

I have a method named readBabyNameData

```
public void readBabyNameData(String filename){
    try{ 

        // open the text file and use a Scanner to read the text
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
        scnr.useDelimiter("[,\r\n]+");
```

In my test class, I'm trying to use this method to input a text file (named MySampleData.txt) I have created (It is in the project folder).

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    BabyNameDatabase db = new BabyNameDatabase();

    db.readBabyNameData("MySampleData.txt");
```

When I run the main method to test my program, it does gives me a InputMismatchException error from the software that I'm using (BlueJay). 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add your code snippets into the question body.

Comment: I've added pictures. If you click "readBabyNameData" and "test class" they will appear

Comment: I see. And this is not the correct way to refer code. Stackoverflow lets you insert code and provides formating for it. You shouldn't use screenshots.

Comment: Please show a sample of the contents of the file.

Comment: Scanner throws an `InputMismatchException` from its various `next*` methods, which isn't in the code snippets you've provided.